# SQL Database Layout including Lists as entries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-indexes

I want to write a simple homepage to track prices of various online stores. I have a scraper, which can read the price of a specific product and I plan on running this scraper maybe once a day some product I'd like to track.

Now I need to store these information and I'm not really sure what a good approach would look like. I think I should create a table for every product I track, which contains two rows: `date` | `price`.

I still have open questions: What should the name for such a table be? The product name? What happens if the product names contains spaces? Or maybe the URL part leading to the product? This seems a little bit unreadable though. Or should I name the table names just to be id's (increasing numbers) and keep a seperate table names `products` containing the rows: `product_name`, `product_url`, `track_table_id`.

This seems like a good idea, since I can add more information to the product later on (a description for example).

Any help on this topic is welcome, since I never touched databases before. Are my considerations reasonable. What other problems might occur?

EDIT: I can't store the complete product data in a single table, since every product contains a variable amount of price points at different points in time.

Comment: IMHO you should have a single `products` table, with the columns or *fields* `product_id`, `product_name`, `url` etc etc ...  This is basic database management  --  It seems you have a lack of understanding how data is stored in a DBMS?

Comment: @Zak Then I'd have one row containing lists (the different prices at different price-points) and I was thinking that no-one wants lists as db entries. How would you handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need 3 tables...  This is a basic **relational** database.

```
1) a product table
2) a pricing table
3) a price point type table
```

Your product table will contain the basics of the product IE `product_id` `product_name` etc etc etc ...

Your product pricing table will include the  price you are wanting to store -- it will also contain a field that relates it to a price point **type**

Your price point type table will contain the different **types**

For example table one will look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Products                          | 
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   product_id    |    product_name    |    product_url    |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|      101        |    Baby Food       |  www.example.com  |
|      102        |  Green Tomatoes    |  www.widget.com   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you have a price point type table

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                  price_point_types                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|    price_point_id    |    type    |    description    |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|         1            |   small    | Small price point |
|         2            |   medium   |   Medium Point    |
|         3            |   large    |   Large  POint    |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

The you have your pricing table:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            pricing                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    id    |    price_point_id    |    product_id    |    price    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    1     |           1          |       101        |    5.00     |
|    2     |           2          |       101        |    10.00    |
|    3     |           3          |       101        |    15.00    |
|    4     |           1          |       102        |    6.00     |
|    5     |           2          |       102        |    9.00     |
|    6     |           3          |       102        |    12.00    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now you can see for product `Baby Food` we have 3 price points of `small`, `medium` and `large` correlating to the prices of `5.00`, `10.00` and `15.00` respectively.  And the same for product `Green Tomatoes`.   This way you can have unlimited price point types and unlimited price points per product ... Make sense?

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense, but I'm still a little bit confused about the price point table. What exactly is it for? Is this for a product which for example comes in multiple sizes and therefore has multiple prices?

Comment: Yes ..  Exactly ..  It's not *technically* a pivot table .. But you can still treat it like one ..  So you can have small, medium, large, green, blue, orange, short, tall, mid -- all in the same table .. It just gives a **description** to your price point.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This seems like a good idea. I didn't come across such products yet and therefore didn't even think about needing such a table.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest some research into RDBMS and database design as well. Here's a good resource to start:

https://www.calebcurry.com/blogs/database-design/what-is-a-relational-database

After that series, try his next level of video's:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7Pr1VgPK4w

Some base-line DB Design is necessary before you undertake the task of creating a database.